# mysqli_query returning null, can't find where I have gone wrong. PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to work with a database in PHP and MySQL and having a problem which I think have segregated to one specific area, but cannot figure out my error.

I can select my database fine and all that passes and success is shown when I run it to make sure it is working correctly, my problem seems to be SELECTing values from the database so I can manipulate them.

My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT theFlashEpsDate FROM superhero WHERE theFlashEps =" . $name;
  $result = mysqli_query($databaseConnection, $sql);

  if(!$result)
  {
    echo "<br>Error on Query";
  }
  if ($result)
  {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $getTheFlashEpsDate = $row[0];
  }
  else
  {
    $getTheFlashEpsDate = null;
  }
  return $getTheFlashEpsDate;
 }
}

$getEpisodeName = $_GET['episodename'];
$objSuperHero = new FlashEpisodes;
$response = $objSuperHero->FlashEpDate($getEpisodeName);
var_dump(json_encode($response));
```

I have a class called FlashEpisodes and a public function called FlashEpDate($name)

As you can see from the query, I am trying to get the date for an episode by typing in its episode name. 'episodename' I know doesn't exist as of yet, and I just manipulate this in the URL for now.

When I run it all, I get this:

```
Success //To database connection
Error on Query
string 'null' (length=4)
```

All my data is inputted into the table and I can see it on phpMyAdmin, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any pointers?

Kieran

Comment: You should use a prepared statement instead of injecting your variable directly in the query. That will solve your problem and protect you against potential sql injection.

Comment: I'm just starting out you see, so I'm just practicing, so I will research prepared statements! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do changes like
$sql = "SELECT theFlashEpsDate FROM superhero WHERE theFlashEps ='".$name."'";
```

Comment: Oh my god that worked! Could you explain what I was doing wrong? Thank you ever so much!

Comment: string column must be enclosed in qoutations

Comment: if you dont enclose in qoutations  the query treat value after = sign as integer

Comment: Ah okay, lesson learned and just starting off with this so practicing! Thank you ever so much!